# Access denied on samba share created with net usershare

Tags: samba, shared-folders, dolphin

When creating a samba shared folder using net usershare command, I can't login to it via Dolphin or other file browsers.  I get as far as an authentication dialog, but not matter what credentials I use, I get the dialog again and again, until I escape, which then gives me an 'Access denied to smb://uname@location/shareFolder.'

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2.  The usershare generated by the usershare add command generates:

```
[ShareName]
path=/home/user/ShareFolder
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:D,DOMAIN\user:F,
guest_ok=n
```

My smb.conf is pretty vanilla:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        netbios name = NETNAME

        usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
        usershare max shares = 100

        log file = /var/log/samba/%m
        log level = 1
```

If it's telling at all, when I run smbclient -U, I get:

```
sudo smbclient -U user //hostname/sharefolder
Enter user's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

This is not the behaviour at all when share are set directly in smb.conf.  The usernames are all real users on the host, as well as in samba (smbpasswd -a user) and are all enabled (smbpasswd -e user).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the fault in the above USERSHARE tdb entry:  it was in the ACL.  I had set it nullify the user rights by setting:

```
usershare_acl=Everyone:D DOMAIN\user:F
```

'Everyone' was set to 'Deny'.  'Everyone' includes, in this case, 'User', as well.  So, setting 'User' to 'Full' access - or anything else, for that matter - was overruled by 'Everyone's ACL.  The moment I removed 'Everyone' from the equation, everything just worked.